# How do I compare two variables against one string in python?

Tags: python, operators

I would like to print a message if either a or b is empty.

This was my attempt

```
a = ""
b = "string"

if (a or b) == "":
    print "Either a or b is empty"
```

But only when both variables contain an empty string does the message print.

How do I execute the print statement only when either a or b is an empty string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more explicit solution would be this:

```
if a == '' or b == '':
    print('Either a or b is empty')
```

In this case you could also check for containment within a tuple:

```
if '' in (a, b):
    print('Either a or b is empty')
```

Comment: The second one is inefficient because a tuple needs to be created then a search performed in it.

Answer (score 4):

```
if not (a and b):
    print "Either a or b is empty"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just do:

```
if ((not a) or (not b)):
   print ("either a or b is empty")
```

Since `bool('')` is False.

Of course, this is equivalent to:

```
if not (a and b):
   print ("either a or b is empty")
```

Note that if you want to check if **both** are empty, you can use operator chaining:

```
if a == b == '':
   print ("both a and b are empty")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if a == "" and b == "":
    print "a and b are empty"
if a == "" or b == "":
    print "a or b is empty"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use:

```
if not any([a, b]):
    print "a and/or b is empty"
```