# Python ShortHand for OR statement

Tags: python, list, syntax

I am trying to check if either of the elements in the list are found inside of the query.

But the code doesn't work

```
if ['time' or 'Time'] in query:
sayTime()
```

Comment: Try printing the value of `['time' or 'Time']`. `if any(elem in query for elem in word_list):` should do the trick. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: simple way, just make use of the `in` operator for both cases i.e check for both lower and upper case words, without having the strings in a list. or you can check it individually and then proceed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare two variables against one string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193782/how-do-i-compare-two-variables-against-one-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to validate a variable `query` contains the string `time` insensitively:

```py
query = 'the Time is up'
if 'time' in query.lower():
    sayTime()
```

If we are looking for very specific variations we can test via an array of acceptable matches:

```py
query = 'the Time is up'
if any([x in query for x in ['time', 'Time']]):
    sayTime()
```

But note that `in` can have false positives when the intent is for exact matches exclusively, for instance `'time' in 'time to die'` is True.

So if we want to do string comparison we can either downcase as previously suggested and do direct comparison.

```py
if 'time' == query.lower():
    sayTime()
```

or check if the query exists `in` a list of acceptable values:

```py
if query in ['time', 'Time']:
    sayTime()
```

In the second example `query = 'TIME'` would not satisfy the if condition, whereas it would in the first example.

Comment: Why is that a false positive? The purpose of `in` with strings is to look for substrings. If he wanted an exact match he'd use `==`.

Comment: The question says are found *inside* the query.

Comment: You are absolutely right... I somehow missed that, interestingly solved his question so I guess I was reading as intended not as written. To that end having a good example of the value of the query would have helped for sure... I will revise this answer to also handle the `in` example better.

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(x in query for x in ('time', 'Time')):
```

But if you just want to do the check case-insensitively, you can do:

```
if 'time' in query.lower():
```

I'm assuming `query` is a string, not a list.

Comment: Your 1st suggestion assumes `query` is a container while the 2nd assumes `query` is a string

Comment: Although it shouldn't make a difference in this specific example, it's best to use [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), no?

Comment: Thanks, that's a new one to me. All examples I've seen in other questions use `lower()`.

Comment: @DeepSpace I think my first should work in either case.

Comment: The problem with using *in* for string evaluation is that it false positives on matches:

>>> 'foo' in 'FOOBAR'.lower()
True

where as when evaluating against a list or tuple:

>>> 'foo' in ['foobar']
False

so while *in* works for lists and strings, the behavior between the two is very different.

Comment: Even if query was a list, it would work.